# JQuery select table cell, next table cell conditionally

Tags: jquery

```
S/N     Name        Result      Action
--------------------------------------
1       Mike        Passed      
2       Mark        Failed      
3       Mary        Failed
```

Based on the table above, I need to:

- Highlight result column in red where the result is Failed
- Provide a "Retry" hyperlink in action column for those have failed.

Something like $('table.td.result).. (I am not sure about the correct syntax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) for example:

```
$("#myTable td:nth-child(3):contains('Failed')").addClass("failed")
       .next().append("<a href='#'>Retry</a>");
```

[You can try it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/LgAdL/).  The [`:nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) part is so we're only looking in  the third column, and someone named "Little Bobby Failed" doesn't cause a match in the second column by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table td:contains('Failed')").css('background-color','red').next('td').append("<a href='http://www.example.com'>Retry</a>");
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/rZGUc/

Answer (score 0):

to select in which you have the "Failed" text, you can use this selector :

`$("td:contains('Failed')")`